# Game leveling system

Tags: php, object-oriented, game

I made this code for simple leveling game.

I think this code may have some issues with security. Also, are there some way to make this code more efficient and reliable?

For level scaling I will use this method. Should I make `lvl`, `xp` and `nxtlevel` variables to array or is that a bad idea?

```
class LevelingSystem
{

  private $_lvl;
  private $_xp;
  private $_nxtlevel;

  function __construct($lvl=1,$xp=0,$nxtlevel=30)
  {

    $this->_lvl=$lvl;
    $this->_xp=$xp;
    $this->_nxtlevel=$nxtlevel;
  }

  function setxp($setxp)
  {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE user_atri SET totalxp =totalxp+".$setxp." WHERE id=1");
    $updatexp=$stmt->execute();
    return $updatexp;
  }

  private function getxp()
  {
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT totalxp FROM user_atri where id=1");
    $query->execute();
    $totalxp=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->_xp=$totalxp["totalxp"];
    return $totalxp["totalxp"];
  }

  function lvl()
  {

    $this->getxp();
    while ($this->_xp>=$this->_nxtlevel)
    {
        $this->_lvl+=1;
        $this->_xp =$this->_xp - $this->_nxtlevel;
        $this->_nxtlevel = round($this->_nxtlevel * 1.6);
    }

    //$levelprint=sprintf("Youre level is: %s ",$this->_lvl);
    //echo $this->_xp;
    //echo "<br>";
    //return $levelprint;
    return $this->_lvl;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: in the book '*Refactoring*' by Martin Fowler,  one of the code smells is "Obsession with elementary types". And the advice is to create/take out variables and move them to another class.

Array is an elementary type. The resolution is to create an entity class `Settings` and set member variables `$lvl,$xp,$nxtlevel`.

Second: `global $db;` transfer through object.

Using global variables is bad practice. If you want to use a Database you should create an object for Database access. Best practice use DI. For PHP one such library is [php-di](http://php-di.org/doc/getting-started.html).

Your code may look like this:

```
<?php

  class LevelingSystem {

  private $settings;
  private $db;

  function __construct(SettingsEntity $settings, DBInterface $db ){
    $this->settings=$settings;
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function setxp($setxp) {
    $result =  $this
                ->db
                ->prepare("UPDATE user_atri SET totalxp =totalxp+" . $setxp . " WHERE id=1")
                ->execute();

    if(!$result) {
       throw new Exception('DB error');  //you can send your exception 
    }        

    return $this;
  }

  public function calcSettings() {
   $xp = $this->getxp();
   $nxtlevel = $this->settings->getNxtlevel();
   $lvl = $this->settings->getLvl();

   while ($xp >= $nxtlevel) {
        $lvl += 1;
        $xp = $xp - $nxtlevel;
        $nxtlevel = round($nxtlevel * 1.6);
    }

     $this->settings
     ->setlvl($lvl)
     ->setXp($xp)
     ->setNxtlevel($nxtlevel);

     return $this;
  }

  public function getLvl() {
      return $this->settings->getLvl();
  }

  private function getxp() {
    $totalxp = $db
                ->prepare("SELECT totalxp FROM user_atri where id=1")
                ->execute()
                ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!isset($totalxp["totalxp"])) {
       throw new Exception('Some DB error'); //you can send your exception 
    } 

    return $totalxp["totalxp"];
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand how my Settings class should look like.

Comment: class SettingsEntity
{


  public $_lvl;
  public $_xp;
  public $_nxtlevel;

  function __construct($lvl=1,$xp=0,$nxtlevel=30)
  {
    $this->_lvl=$lvl;
    $this->_xp=$xp;
    $this->_nxtlevel=$nxtlevel;
  }

  function setXp($xp)
  {
      $this->_xp=$xp;
  }

  function setlvl($lvl)
  {
      $this->_lvl=$lvl;
  }

  function setNxtlevel($nxtlevel)
  {
      $this->_nxtlevel=$nxtlevel;
  }

  function getLvl()
  {
      return $this->_lvl;
  }

  function getNxtlevel()
  {
      return $this->_nxtlevel;
  }


}

Comment: this what I made, but it aint working

Comment: nvm, got it working, I forgot to add return $this to set functions

Comment: add call chain. For example in SettingsEntity method setlvl most return `$this`.  all Setters most return $this.  `setlvl($lvl) { $this->_lvl=$lvl; return $this;}`